# Is there an easy way to remove gradle?

Tags: gradle

I was given a reasonably simple Java program (2K lines of code) that was created by someone else.  My job is to modify it.  This code currently uses gradle to build/compile/run, or whatever gradle does.  I don't really want to ramp up and learn gradle.  Instead, I want to remove gradle from the build/compile/run loop completely.  Is there an easy way to do that without knowing anything about gradle?  Maybe a command-line option that displays all the steps gradle is doing so I can then put those steps in a script and run them manually?